# How to get import function to location files?

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error (warning: Python GUI libraries (tkinter) not found command-line usage: decrypt_bitcoinj_seed.pyw bitcoinj-wallet-file) since I have tkinter installed correctly and the test shows it is working correctly. Apparently the `decrypt_bitcoinj_seed.pyw` file can't locate the Python Lib files that contain `tkinter` and `ttk, FileDialog, SimpleDialog, MessageBox` as well. Do you know how to overcome this error or more specifically, how to get import `tkinter`, etc. to work? How does the command `import tkinter` know where to look so it can find the modules `ttk, tkFileDialog, tkSimpleDialog, tkMessageBox` in the following path: `C:\Python38\Lib\tkinter`? I have checked and all the files are there. Do you know how I can make the `decrypt_bitcoinj_seed.pyw` file look in path `C:\Python38\Lib\tkinter` so it can import the files?

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/1509809) to add path for importing.

Comment: Is `C:\Python38` the chosen directory when you installed Python 3.8? If yes, then `C:\Python38\Lib` should be already included in the module search path.  Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Hi, I cheated and put except "ImportError" in the code because I was tired of tying for days to figure this out!  I put this in my code as seen below:                                                                                   
        try:
            import tkinter as tk
            from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, simpledialog, messagebox
        except ImportError:
            print('warning: Python GUI libraries (tkinter) not found')
            sys.exit('command-line usage: decrypt_bitcoinj_seed.pyw bitcoinj-wallet-file')